# Add admin page for specific post status (for example)

Tags: customization, wp-admin

I have posts in the wordpress administration. These posts have statuses and an author
I would like to be able to create several types of pages in the wordpress administration which will be identical to the edit.php page (but without the "Add new" button and without the filters), for example a page where all the posts have the status "ready to publish ", a page where all the posts are authored by" John Doe "...
I have no idea how to do this, do you have any leads please?

Comment: These pages already exist, there's filters and links at the top of the post list page, you can click on the author names in the post list to filter by user. URL parameters ca apply changes to any admin post list

Comment: thanks but how to remove filters in these cases ? and if the user edit url parameters to see a page to which he has no access ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if a user can view posts, then they can view posts. If they can't view posts then it doesn't matter what URL they use, they can't view that page regardless of the parameters and URL options they add. I'm also not sure why you would remove those filters when your question is asking how to create them

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry. I want to hide filter like "Bulk actions" and links like "All", "Published".. and I don't know how to do this could you help me ? And how to allow an user to see a post in the wordpress administration but not edit it ?

Comment: Ah, are those new questions or the same question as what you posted above? We have a 1 question per question policy here, but you can have multiple questions on the site at the same time, just not smushed into a single one. Remember this isn't a discussion forum.The last question about read only/view only posts in admin has already been asked and answered on the site ( it's not possible ), as has removing bulk actions, and removing the links ( not sure why you want that as it gives you exactly what your original question asked for ).

Comment: Yes it's the same question. I would like to create admin page who looks like "Posts" but only with the actual user's posts and without the filters like "Bulk actions" and links like "All", "Published", off course, if the user edit the URL parameters he couldn't see the page

Comment: So you want to keep the original posts admin page? Or you're replacing it? Or have an additional page? This is quite a broad question, and a lot of work. Where do these new pages appear? Why do you want it? What is the problem it solves? Remember, this isn't a discussion forum, your question need to be clear and specific, make sure to edit your question so that it contains everything needed to understand the question ( do not rely on people reading the comments )